# DSO missing from command line although it is available

Tags: linker, g++, ld

I am working with c++ code for a physics simulation, which uses a lot of external libraries (like GSL and cern`s ROOT). Trying to recompile project I encountered problems with linking. When running compilation of final file via:

```
g++ -fno-inline -O2 -fpic -o main.out ${ROOTINCS} main.o ext.o ${ROOTLIBS} $(objects2)
```

with :

- objects2= many .o files made by us
- ROOTLIBS=-L/usr/local/lib/root  -lTree -lRIO -lNet -lHist -lMathCore -lCore -lGraf -lGraf3d -lGpad -lMatrix -lThread -lCint -lPhysics -lPostscript -lRint  -lSpectrum  -lg
- ROOTINCS=-pthread -m64

I get annoying error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/root/libHist.so: undefined reference to symbol 'gRandom'

/usr/local/lib/root/libMathCore.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem is nm -C run on libMathCore states 'gRandom' is declared there. Also -lMathCore is present in my command line.

When I run ld to check if it understands the flag:

```
ld -L/usr/local/lib/root -lMathCore --verbose 2>/dev/null
```

it does not complain and tries to link properly.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24675715/3602168 order of libraries is correct in my linking (libHist uses libMathCOre and therefore is stated first).

Compilation runs under g++ 4.8.2 on ubuntu 14.04, 64 bit

Comment: Have you tried moving `$(objects2)` before `${ROOTLIBS}`?  I think the issue may be that you have libraries specified before the object files that use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to answer:

Have you tried moving `$(objects2)` before `${ROOTLIBS}?` I think the issue may be that you have libraries specified before the object files that use them.